# What is wrong with this query? psql

Tags: php, psql

Objective: to return all records of a given type where the opposite type does not exist.

Problem: No records are returned when I use the Select Count as an 'AND'

```
SELECT ct.cntrct_id, ar.addr_1, ar.city_nm, ar.st_cd, ar.zip_code, p.phone_nbr, p.frst_nm, p.lst_nm
    FROM addru ad, addrs ar, cntrt ct, persn p, custm cm
    WHERE ad.cntrct_seq = ct.cntrct_seq
    AND ar.addr_seq = ad.addr_seq
    AND p.person_seq = cm.person_seq
    AND cm.clnt_seq = ct.clnt_seq
    AND ad.active_flg = '1'
    AND ad.dist_id = $dist
    AND substring(ct.cntrct_id from 2 for 1) = '$type'
    AND ((SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM addru ad, addrs ar, cntrt ct, persn p, custm cm
            WHERE ad.cntrct_seq = ct.cntrct_seq
            AND ar.addr_seq = ad.addr_seq
            AND p.person_seq = cm.person_seq
            AND cm.clnt_seq = ct.clnt_seq
            AND ad.active_flg = '1'
            AND ad.dist_id = $dist
            AND substring(ct.cntrct_id from 2 for 1) != '$type') = 0)
    ORDER BY ct.cntrct_id"
```

Copying the table definitions will take up a lot of space, so if you need to see them, let me know which ones (don't want to bog down the question with too much info)  I think my error is a logical one or stems from a misunderstanding of how to form the sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, why can't you do

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0
```

This should be better than running the query twice just so you can do 'inline' count filtering at the row level.

Comment: The reason I chose to do Select Count as opposed to Having is that I don't know how to include the conditions I need in the count(*)

Comment: Marc, I used "HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN substring(ct.cntrct_id from 2 for 1) != '$type' THEN 1 END) = 0"  This seemed to generate the appropriate records.  I got an error when I used ORDER BY so I took it out.  Since you suggested using HAVING, I will accept as answer, though only time will tell if the query is generating accurate records (may have to ask this one again).  Thanks